# Using devise_token_auth with jsonapi-resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, jsonapi-resources

I am trying to use devise_token_auth with jsonapi-resources.  I have it set up where I can create users and sign in, but I cannot figure out how to access a controller that has needs to authenticate a user first.  Here is my controller that I am trying to require authentication:

```
class FriendsController < JSONAPI::ResourceController
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

When I try `localhost:3000/friends`, I get a 401 "Authorized users only." error, so I think it works.  I think my main problem is Im not sure what to do with the access-token I get when I sign in.  I have tried setting it in the header in my request, but still get the same "Authorized users only" error.

Answer (score 2):

Better a late answer than none... devise_token_auth and jsonapi_resources work pretty well for me in a test setup. But, you need to set the request header correctly. It is not enough to transmit the "auth-token" header, you also heave to transmit the "client" token, the "uid" and the "token-type" header as well. Although I'm not entirely sure if the latter is actually required.

Answer (score 0):

Devise token authentication is quite independent of `jsonapi-resources`. If you can get token authentication working (as explained in this answer, for example: [Custom devise api token auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970504/custom-devise-api-token-auth)) you can simply extend your controller (or your ApplicationController) with the authentication concern and it should behave as a normal Rails controller would.